# Most frequent word in MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I got a MongoDB collection where each entry has a product field containing a string array. What i would like to do is find the most frequent word in the whole collection. Any ideas on how to do that ?

Here is a sample object:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55e02d333b88f425f84191af"),
    "product" : [ 
        " x bla y "
    ],
    "hash_key" : "ecfe355b2f45dfbaf361cff4d314d4cc",
    "price" : [ 
        "z"
    ],
    "image" : "image_url"
}
```

Looking at the sample object, what I would like to do is count "x", "bla" and "y" singularly.

Comment: shows us the sample document and the sample output. so that we can help you.

Comment: I would suggest using either [Map-Reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/map-reduce/) or [Aggregation Pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

Comment: mapReduce is the "only" way to do this as you would be effectively "splitting strings" to find the "words". It also gets a bit invoved as if you want "blueberry" and "blueberries" to both count as "blueberry" then that would be a lot of JavaScript logic. Also the potential output is "huge" since you have no other option than to emit and therefore have "results" of one record for every word that is contained within the collection. And all that just to then find the result with the largest count. Hadoop or similar might be a better choice. If you can spare the hardware.

Comment: By most frequent string, do you mean (in your example) instance of `" x bla y "`

Comment: I mean the most frequent word (I edited the question for clarity). In my example I mean, "x", "bla" and "y" separately.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to do something similar. I had a collection of objects and each object had a list of keywords. To count the frequency of each keyword, I used the following aggregation pipeline, which uses the MongoDB version 4.4 $accumulator group operation.

```
db.collectionname.aggregate(
    {$match: {available: true}},  // Some criteria to filter the documents
    {$project: 
        { _id: 0, keywords: 1}},                            // Only keep keywords
    {$group: 
        {_id: null, keywords:                               // Accumulate keywords into one array
            {$accumulator: {
                init: function(){return new Array()}, 
                accumulate: function(state, value){return state.concat(value)}, 
                accumulateArgs: ["$keywords"], 
                merge: function(state1, state2){return state1.concat(state2)}, 
                lang: "js"}}}}, 
    {$unwind: "$keywords"},                                 // Split array into fields
    {$group: {_id: "$keywords", freq: {$sum: 1}}},          // Group keywords and count frequencies
    {$sort: {freq: -1}},                                    // Sort in reverse order
    {$limit: 5}                                             // Take first five
)
```

I have no idea if this is the most efficient solution. However, it solved the problem for me.