# How to do a word count in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Can anyone recommend a way that I can do this Python code as a MongoDB query?

```
import pandas as pd 
data = pd.read_csv("elonmusk.csv") 
from collections import Counter
Counter(" ".join(data["tweet"]).split()).most_common(100)
```

I am looking for help to write a MongoDB query that can create a similar output as the Python code shown here.

Analysing all the text of one field and returning the most common words.

[image]

I believe MongoDB word cloud link here has a similar solution https://docs.mongodb.com/charts/saas/chart-type-reference/word-cloud/
However I have to write the code in the MongoDB shell.

I was not sure how to apply the following Stackoverflow solution in this link [Most frequent word in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32520969/most-frequent-word-in-mongodb-collection)

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: How is the data stored in MongoDB?

Comment: the database is called elonmusk, the table/collection is called Tweets, tweet is a field from within the collection. It was originally imported into MongoDB from Kaggle csv dataset

Answer (score 1):

Query

- query assumes that the text is on tweet field
- match to find the words with regex (word contains only alphanumeric characters here)
- unwind
- group and count
- `$set` to fix structure (you can use project also its the same)
- sort by word count
- limit to keep only the 100 most popular words

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=62b39cfa91b564fc1e7e95be)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$type": "$tweet"}, "string"]}}},
 {"$set": 
    {"matches": {"$regexFindAll": {"input": "$tweet", "regex": "\\w+"}}}},
 {"$project": {"tokens": "$matches.match"}},
 {"$unwind": {"path": "$tokens"}},
 {"$group": {"_id": "$tokens", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
 {"$set": {"word": "$_id", "_id": "$$REMOVE"}},
 {"$sort": {"count": -1}},
 {"$limit": 100}])
```

Comment: Hi Takis_ 
I really appreciate your solution. I had a few issues trying to run it.
First I got the error ….. aggregate is not defined, so I added the collections name before your code. db.Tweets.aggregate(  Now I get this error …. $regexFindAll needs 'input' to be of type string" I had earlier set the tweet field to a text index but I have dropped the index and I am still getting the error
$regexFindAll needs 'input' to be of type string"
So I have checked what type the field is:
typeof db.Tweet.findone().tweet
it returns string
Any suggestions?

Comment: some document(s) doesn't have string tweet, this is not a problem, `$match` can keep only the documents that have tweet as string. I updated the answer.

Comment: That works perfectly Takis, I  just had to make one small edit to get it to work in the shell and that was prefix the code with db. and the collection name Tweets.

Comment: db.Tweets.aggregate(
[{"$match": {"$expr": {"$eq": [{"$type": "$tweet"}, "string"]}}},
 {"$set": 
    {"matches": {"$regexFindAll": {"input": "$tweet", "regex": "\\w+"}}}},
 {"$project": {"tokens": "$matches.match"}},
 {"$unwind": {"path": "$tokens"}},
 {"$group": {"_id": "$tokens", "count": {"$sum": 1}}},
 {"$set": {"word": "$_id", "_id": "$$REMOVE"}},
 {"$sort": {"count": -1}},
 {"$limit": 100}])